# Coldfuson or Regular Expression find all URLs in string ending with Page .doc, .txt, .pdf

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have Coldfusion web page and need code either Coldfusion or a Regular Expression to strip out URL's (multiple) in a string. They are run together with no line breaks or commas separating them. Note all the URLs are 'full' meaning they end with a page or document file type ending in '.doc' or '.txt' or '.pdf'.

example string = "http://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202_to-pmod7-ep.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.com/ap

ps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202_to-pmod7-ep.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage

/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202h-data.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202_to-pmod7-

ep.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202_to-pmod7-ep.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.co

m/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202h-data.pdf"

Either a Coldfusion or Regular Expression would help! Thanks.

Comment: Any chance of a snippet of the string you are trying to pull these urls out of? I can think of a number of possible solutions, but can't visualise the data you are working with.

Comment: string = "http://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202_to-pmod7-ep.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202_to-pmod7-ep.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202h-data.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202_to-pmod7-ep.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202_to-pmod7-ep.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202h-data.pdf"

Comment: You mention multiple pages, so what does the second and third page look like in your string? Also, edit your original post to add the sample string instead of posting it in the comments.

Comment: if you look at the string for every occurrence of http:// in the string there is the url and the full path (down to the document associataed with it), then the next http:// in the string and so on...

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfscript>
examplestring = "http://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202_to-pmod7-ep.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202_to-pmod7-ep.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202h-data.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202_to-pmod7-ep.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202_to-pmod7-ep.pdfhttp://xxxx.xxxx.com/apps/libs/hdldocs/pwr_voltage/lmz14202/docs/lmz14202h-data.pdf";
aHREF = examplestring.split("http://");
</cfscript>
```

I wrote it as a script block, but it works just as well with standard cfset calls.

You end up with an array of urls with the http:// stripped off the front. If the first thing in the string is a url, then you will end up with an empty array element in the first position, but that should give you a good start.  It should also be considerably quicker than using the ColdFusion functions with large quantities of data as it goes direct to the underlying java.lang.String object.

Comment: If you do `string.split("(?<!\A)(?=http://)")` then you don't need to restore the `http://` part and it doesn't create the empty array element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset myurls = ListToArray(ReplaceNoCase(str, "http://", "#chr(7)#http://", "all"), chr(7))>
```

as user662486 pointed out, there is not reason to do this with a regular expression. the code above will return an array with each element containing the full url.

Comment: This method will scan the text once to find each `http://` and then prefix them with `chr(7)`, then go through the string a second time to break into an array at each `chr(7)`. Using the split method only needs to scan the string once and doesn't need to modify it, so is likely to be faster (though probably not to a significant level). I'd also say it's easier to read what's going on with split method, even with the regex lookaround stuff.